# What is the maximum limit of ssh connections to a linux box

Tags: linux, ssh, cpu, sshd

Configuration assumption:

2 core CPU
4 GB RAM
HDD: 20 GB

Question I:

1. I want to know at least the approximate connections that we can establish for the Linux machine

I know we can set the max ssh in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. I need the direct answer if someone knows it.

Question II:

If I establish the connections through SSH relay and hold for a while the machine is hitting with 100 % CPU Utilization.
even if I create for 5 sessions or 500 sessions.

What is the reason for it?

Comment: The maximum number of connections would probably be equal to the maximum number of TCP connections possible. That would be the theoretical number. You already hinted as possible configurations that might prevent you from reaching that limit. Did you check that SSH is responsible for that 100% utilization and not some other process?

Comment: A lot. A “2 core CPU” could also be anything. Please try to limit yourself to one question. It seems your second question is the actual problem you’re trying to solve.

Comment: @Daniel B: Thanks for the reply and suggestion.

Comment: @seth: I checked that apart from SSH sessions there is some hidden process/processes is causing the problem. I need to find those. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Would it not show up by simply running `htop` or similar? Did you verify whenever the output for CPU utilization does add up or how much is missing from it?